# NSUserDefault don't access value in a sandbox MacOS app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, sandbox

I found after configuring my app sandbox, I can not access the preference value.

According the online blog, I have set `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write` to YES in entitlements. Did I miss something?

[Entitlements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1pWm.png)

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// Once using sandbox mode, the value is nil.
NSString *value = [defaults objectForKey:@"MyPreference"];
```

ps: The preference key is correct, because when I close the sandbox, the preference value can be read normally.

Comment: User defaults are stored in different locations for sandboxed and non-sandboxed apps. So it is expected that you sandboxed version can not read the defaults set when it was not sandboxed. You should be able to write and then read defaults from your sandboxes version though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Gerd K.

> User defaults are stored in different locations for sandboxed and non-sandboxed apps.

In sandboxed app, the user default(`.plist`) is stored in `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Containers/xiaofeihan.MyWebViewSample/Data/Library/Preferences`

In non-sandboxed app, it is stored in `Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences`